# Evaluating many random states in python

Tags: python, random-forest

I am working with python and I have a code that looks like this.

```
for index in range (1, 5):
Rndm1 = RFC(n_estimators=500, random_state= index)
Rndm1.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = Rndm1.predict(x_test)
print("selected random state:", index)
print("Accuracy:", accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

And I get a result like this ...

```
selected random state: 3
Accuracy: 0.95
```

The problem is that I only get one random state, and I actually want all five random states and their accuracies. So how can it get a result like this...

```
selected random state: 1
Accuracy: 0.94

selected random state: 2
Accuracy: 0.96

selected random state: 3
Accuracy: 0.95

selected random state: 4
Accuracy: 0.93

selected random state: 5
Accuracy: 0.96
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand how the first set of results appears. Where is `selected random state` coming from? The `for` loop and print statements imply that the output should already look something like: `(1, accuracy)`, `(2, accuracy)`, ..., `(4, accuracy)`.

Comment: Do you mean you want to fit multiple classifiers? In that case you could add 5 classifiers in a list, iterate over the list of classifiers, and fit each on a set of training data.

Comment: Sorry @Alexander L Hayes, The selected random states were an error. I forgot to write the word selected in the print line. I just need to run the model with many random states in order to calculate the mean of accuracy across many random states.

Answer (score 1):

Accumulate the intermediate accuracies into a list, then take the mean of the list:

```py
import numpy as np

accuracies = []

for index in range(1, 5):
    Rndm1 = RFC(n_estimators=500, random_state= index)
    Rndm1.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = Rndm1.predict(x_test)
    accuracies.append(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))

print("Mean across random states", np.mean(accuracies))
```